# Apache: Action directive not activating CGI script

Tags: apache, perl, cgi, action, directive

I have been playing around with Apache CGI and am trying to run a CGI script when a specific file extension is requested.

I have the following in my apache2.conf:

```
AddHandler handle .html
Action handle /use/lib/cgi-bin/test.pl virtual

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

So when I try to request an html page, Hello.html, from my DocumentRoot directory I get an error message that says it could not find a path which combines the location of my CGI script and requested file:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /usr/lib/cgi-bin/test.pl/hello.html was not found on
>   this server. Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at ryan-virtualbox Port
>   80Not Found

Why would my CGI script not run, and why is this combined path presented as Not Found?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [mod_actions documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod%5factions.html#action), the cgi-script is the URL-path to a resource.
So I guess your Action directive should be rewritten:

```
Action handle /cgi-bin/test.pl virtual
```